# Is there a way to pass property.method to .where() instead of property in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

My Schedule model looks like this:

```
    create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer  "week_day"
        t.time     "opening_time"
        t.time     "closing_time"
        t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
        t.integer  "taco_place_id"
      end
add_index "schedules", ["taco_place_id"], name: "index_schedules_on_taco_place_id"
```

As you can see, there are opening_time and closing_time properties and I have a realtionship Schedule belongs_to :taco_place and TacoPlace has_many :schedules, dependent: :destroy.

What I am trying to do from the Schedule model is to get the actual schedule for a TacoPlace for today (if it exists).

I have already implemented a scope for having today's schedules for a TacoPlace (depending on the week_day property) that looks like this:

```
scope :today_for_taco_place, ->(taco_place){where(taco_place_id: taco_place.id, week_day: Time.now.wday)}
```

and I'm using it in this method:

```
def self.actual_for_taco_place(taco_place)
    today = self.today_for_taco_place(taco_place)
    today.where("opening_time <= :now and closing_time >= :now", now: Time.now.utc).first 
end
```

I have tested it and it "works". The thing is that if I run "Schedule.first.opening_time" on the console I get "2000-01-01 06:00:00 UTC". As you can see, it does not only include the time, but also the day (even if it was seeded as "opening_time: "15:00".to_time, closing_time: "24:00".to_time").

Finally, here is the question:

Is there a way that I can run something like this: (I know this won't work yet)

```
def self.actual_for_taco_place(taco_place)
        today = self.today_for_taco_place(taco_place)
        today.where("#{opening_time.strftime("%H%M")} <= :now and #{closing_time.strftime("%H%M") >= :now", now: Time.now.utc.strftime("%H%M")).first 
    end
```

So that the .where() method doesn't look for the property (opening_time or closing_time), but rather perform the strftime() method so I can compare **the time only**? Or should I save the opening_time and closing_time as integers (i.e. "1200") or manually convert them in a method?

Sorry if my question was long or hard to understand. Thank you in advance for your advise.

Comment: I would suggest storing and looking up the opening and closing times as a simple offset from midnight, rather than a time value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening_time and closing_time are now integers. I figured out that I don't gain anything from it being a "time" instead of an "integer" since it is only representing an hour.